# Solace Unauthorized with Kafka Connect JMS Connector

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, solace

I am trying to connect to Solace JMS with Kafka Connect JMS Source Connect (by datamountaineer), and I keep getting unauthorized at smfclient4. I am sure that the username and password are correct. The log is as below.

```
[2018-01-10 07:52:49,859] INFO Connecting to host 'orig=tcp://solace-ip, scheme=tcp://, host=solace-ip' (host 1 of 1, smfclient 2, attempt 1 of 1, this_host_attempt: 1 of 1) (com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel:2337)
[2018-01-10 07:52:50,031] INFO Connected to host 'orig=tcp://solace-ip, scheme=tcp://, host=solace-ip' (smfclient 2) (com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel:2341)
[2018-01-10 07:52:50,222] INFO Channel Closed (smfclient 2) (com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel:460)
[2018-01-10 07:52:50,240] INFO Connecting to host 'orig=tcp://solace-ip, scheme=tcp://, host=solace-ip' (host 1 of 1, smfclient 4, attempt 1 of 2147483647, this_host_attempt: 1 of 1) (com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel:2337)
[2018-01-10 07:52:50,591] INFO (Client name: client-dns.c/3570/#00320002   Local addr: client-ip:52016   Remote addr: solace-ip:55003) - Error Response (401) - Unauthorized (com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpChannel:226)
[2018-01-10 07:52:50,595] INFO Connection attempt failed to host 'solace-ip' ConnectException ((Client name: client-dns.c/3570/#00320002   Local addr: client-ip:52016   Remote addr: solace-ip:55003) - )  com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPErrorResponseException: 401: Unauthorized [Subcode:1] ((Client name: client-dns.c/3570/#00320002   Local addr: client-ip:52016   Remote addr: solace-ip:55003) - ) (com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel:2377)
```

The Kafka Connect configuration is as below. I need to add username:password to connect.jms.url. If not, I get Unauthenticated Authentication.

```
connector.class: "com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.jms.source.JMSSourceConnector"
connect.jms.initial.context.factory: "com.solacesystems.jndi.SolJNDIInitialContextFactory"
connect.jms.initial.context.extra.params: "SOLACE_JMS_VPN=my_vpn"
connect.jms.connection.factory: "MY.CF"
connect.jms.url: "smf://username:password@solace-ip"
connect.jms.username: "username@my_vpn"
connect.jms.kcql: "insert into kafka_topic select * from solaceQ WITHTYPE QUEUE"
```

I tried to tag datamountaineer, but I couldn't find datamountaineer tag.

Any clue on the issue? Aside from this, what do smfclient 2, 4, 6, and 8 mean?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to connect using this username, vpn and password using another tool? For example SDKPerf (available on the Solace Dev site)

It's quite possible that the client profile or ACL profile doesn't give you enough permissions.